# disable function template specialization or overload with constexpr variable

Tags: c++, template-specialization, enable-if, glog

I have in an upstream library a templated function that I want to specialize:

```cpp
/// glog/logging.h
namespace google {
  template <typename T>
  inline void MakeCheckOpValueString(std::ostream* os, const T& v) {
    (*os) << v;
  }
} // namespace google
```

I did so by defining in my code

```cpp
namespace google {
  template <>
  inline void MakeCheckOpValueString<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::ostream* os, const Duration& d) {
    (*os) << v.cound();
  }
} // namespace google
```

I would like to disable this specialization at compile time (i.e. not through preprocessor macros) with something along the lines of

```cpp
constexpr bool provide_my_specializations = ...;

template <std::enable_if<provide_my_specializations>>
  inline void MakeCheckOpValueString<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::ostream* os, const Duration& d)
```

But I didn't find a way where to put the `enable_if` into the template specialization. Is it possible to enable/disable a template specialization with sfinae, **without** modifying the general template?

EDIT:

given the comment, I tried using a function overload, though fail to find the right place for sfinae disabling either

```cpp
constexpr bool SWITCH = false;

namespace glog {
inline std::enable_if_t<SWITCH, void> MakeCheckOpValueString(std::ostream* os, const Duration& v) {
  (*os) << v.count();
}
}
```

[compiler-explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/6W1q7c)

EDIT2:

The function that I'm trying to specialize is not used by me, but in the upstream library itself, so I can't call a different (wrapping) object instead as that would require editing the call sites upstream.

(turns out that makes the overloading instead of specialization trickier - while not impossible

```cpp
// glog/logging.h
namespace google {
template <typename T>
inline void MakeCheckOpValueString(std::ostream* os, const T& v) {
  (*os) << v;
}
tempate <typename T1, typename T2>
std::string* MakeCheckOpString(const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const char* exprtext) {
  base::CheckOpMessageBuilder comb(exprtext);
  MakeCheckOpValueString(comb.ForVar1(), v1);
  MakeCheckOpValueString(comb.ForVar2(), v2);
  return comb.NewString();
}

// my code
// non-templated overload of MakeCheckOpValueString needs to go here
#include <glog/logging.h>
// template specialization of MakeCheckOpValueString can go here

/*
code that eventually instantiates MakeCheckOpString comes here
*/
)
```

Comment: Don't specialize.  Instead, add an overload.  template function specializations should be avoided.

Comment: @NathanOliver okay, does that allow pushing compile time removal of the definition in? (included my attempt in the edit)

Comment: check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184824/why-does-this-dependent-type-not-count-as-specialization-using-the-template-argu

Comment: @bakaDev I might be missing something in that post but i don't see where that explains the disabling of the specialization(/overload) through complie time bools.

Comment: @NathanOliver care to elaborate (or reference) the advantages of overloading vs template specialization? I noticed in the concrete case, template specialization gives a bit more liberty about where to put the definition (and thus downstream of me no worries about include orders)

Comment: @pseyfert See: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52760860/4342498

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::enable_if_t<false>` is invalid (for any specialization).

To make it SFINAE friendly, you have to make the condition dependent:

```
constexpr bool SWITCH = false;

namespace glog {

template <bool b = SWITCH>
std::enable_if_t<b> MakeCheckOpValueString(std::ostream* os, const Duration& v) {
  (*os) << v.count();
}
}
```

Comment: Given what I noticed in edit2 (sensitivity to where my overload/specialization would need to go), I would prefer a specialization of the upstream template over an overload (so i can pack my implementation into a header and don't need to worry about include orders). Is there also a solution with template specialization?

Comment: I would say `std::conditional_t<SWITCH, MyType, DummyType<MyType>>`, so overload still exist but for dummy types.

Answer (score 0):

in this code you can control specialization if you use a wrapper like the proxy class in here that is control able via the active_sp variable.

```
using namespace std;


constexpr bool active_sp = true;

template <typename T>
struct hello
{
    void operator()()
    { 
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
};


struct SomeOtherType{};


template <template <typename> class m, typename T, bool active = active_sp>
struct Proxy
{
    void operator()()
    {
        m<T>()();
    }
};

template <template <typename> class m>
struct Proxy<m, SomeOtherType, true>
{
    void operator()()
    {
        cout << "hi" << endl;
    }
};

template <template <typename> class m, typename T>
struct Proxy<m, T, false>
{
    void operator()()
    {
        m<T>()();
    }
};

int main()
{
    hello<int>()();

    Proxy<hello, int>()();
    Proxy<hello, SomeOtherType>()();
    return 0;
}
```