# Template specialization of an inner class of a template class

Tags: c++, templates

Given following code

```
template<typename T>
struct A{
  struct In{};

};

template<typename T>
struct Desc{
};


template<typename X>
struct Desc<typename A<X>::In> {
};



int main(){
  Desc<A<int>::In> a;
}
```

the compiler refuses the Desc specialization with

```
error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
error:         ‘X’
```

Same if the struct is defined by

```
template<>
template<typename X>
struct Desc<typename A<X>::In> {
};
```

Definition

```
template<typename X>
template<>
struct Desc<typename A<X>::In> {
};
```

gives the error

```
desc.cpp:14:10: error: invalid explicit specialization before ‘>’ token
desc.cpp:14:10: error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized
desc.cpp:15:8: error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
desc.cpp:15:8: error:         ‘X’
```

Is this a case of "non-deduced context" as here?

[Template parameters not used in partial specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398912/template-parameters-not-used-in-partial-specialization)

It would make sense, since there's no guarantee that the inner class is actually a class (we know only that it is a typename, it may be a typedef).
Is there then a way to specify it's a real class?

Comment: I'm afraid that is the case. Can't you just specialise for `A<x>`? Inside the specialisation you can use `A<x>::In` everywhere, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there then a way to specify it's a real class**

No, there is no way to specify, if you use this type in partial template specialization.

There are only two ways. Specialize `Desc` for concrete `A`, so,

```
template<>
struct Desc<typename A<type>::In> { };
```

or use something like

```
template<typename T, typename  = void>
struct Desc{
};


template<typename X>
struct Desc<X, typename A<X>::In> {
};
```

or of course specialize for type `A<X>` not for `A<X>::In`.

Comment: I doubt that his `A<X>::In` is `void`.